# How to do scope with subquery

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a model Partner_deal which has lots of fields but the only one you really need to know about is called quantity which is an integer that specifies how many times the deal can be redeemed.

I then have another model Partner_deal_redemption to keep track of the redemptions. This has a partner_deal_id column and a user_id column to record which users have redeemed which deal.

I want to create a scope in my Partner_deal model so that it will only return deals where the number of redemptions is less than the quantity field.

I know how to do this in MySql by doing a subquery that counts how many redemptions each deal has had and uses a HAVING clause to filter out the ones where the number of redemptions = quantity.

I have no idea where to begin doing this in eloquent, this is my best attempt:

```
function scopeNotRunOut($query)
{
    return $query->having('quantity', '>', function($q)
           {
               $q->from('partner_deal_redemptions')
                 ->selectRaw('count(*)')
                 ->where('partner_deal_id', '=', 'id');
           });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use the has() function of Eloquent:

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#querying-relations

```
function scopeNotRunOut($query)
{
    return $query->has('redemptions', '<', DB::raw('quantity'));
}
```

To use this function you need to define the `redemptions` function in your Partner_deal model, which will represent the relation between the Partner_deal and the Partner_deal_redemption models.

Comment: Hi first of all thank you so much that does what I needed :-) however I've just spotted another issue. A deal doesn't necessarily have a limit so the quantity field is NULL in that case. Is there a way to modify it so that it checks where quantity is null OR redemptions < quantity?

Answer (score 0):

[MrShibby](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3170216/mrshibby) was correct but then I realised I needed to check if quantity was null as well so I modified his solution slightly to the following:

```
function scopeNotRunOut($query)
{
    return $query->where(function($q) {
        $q->orHas('redemptions', '<', DB::raw('quantity'))
          ->orWhere('quantity', '=', null);
    });
}
```